# difference in with/without "left join" and matching in "where" or "on"?

Tags: sql

Is there any performance difference between two different SQL-codes as below? The first one is without `left jon` and matching with `where`, the other is with `left join` and matching with `on`.

Because I get exactly the same result/output from those sql's, but I will be working with bigger tables soon (like couple of billions rows), so I don't want to have any performance issues. Thanks in advance ...

```
select a.customer_id
from table a, table b 
where a.customer_id = b.customer_id


select a.customer_id
from table a 
left join table b 
on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

Comment: The question is: do you want a left join or an inner join?

Comment: The 2 sql snippets do different things

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick: Using old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). `inner join` was added to standard SQL in 1992. That means the comma-style join has been outdated for quarter of a *century*.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. It is my ignorance that I didnt notice that comma-process is a inner-join, and it was just chance that I get the same results in both cases.

Comment: If the question is: "*is there a performance difference between the old, ancient and fragile implicit join and the explicit JOIN operator*" the answer is: NO. If the question is: "*is there a performance difference between an inner join and an outer join*" then the answer is: most probably yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two do different things and yes, there is a performance impact.

Your first example is a `cross join` with a filter which reduces it to an `inner join` (virtually all planners are smart enough to reduce this to an `inner join` but it is semantically a `cross join` and filter).

Your second is a `left join` which means that where the filter is not met, you will still get all records from table a.

This means that the planner has to assume all records from table a are relevant, and that correlating records from table b are relevant in your second example, but in your first example it knows that only correlated records are relevant (and therefore has more freedom in planning).

In a very small data set you will see no difference but you may get different results.  In a large data set, your `left join` can never perform better than your `inner join` and may perform worse.

Comment: surprinsingly good explanation with no SQL code snippet or schemas at all :)